# amcharts v3 add legend to radar chart

Tags: legend, amcharts

I like to add a legend to my radar chard but i can not seem to connect the legend data to the dataprovider data

Here is my javascript code:

```
   AmCharts.makeChart("360_radar_chartdiv", 
  {"type": "radar",         
  "dataProvider": [  
   {"competence": "test Ronald","user_15": 7.5,"user_16": 7.5,"user_18": 1,"user_23": 5},
   {"competence": "Aansturen","user_15": 5,"user_16": 7,"user_18": 8,"user_23": 3}],
    "valueAxes":  [      
           {"axisTitleOffset": 20, "minimum": 0,"maximum": 10, "axisAlpha": 0.15}],
   "startDuration": 0       ,
   "graphs": [       
              {"balloonText": "[[value]]", "bullet": "round","valueField": "user_15"},
              {"balloonText": "[[value]]", "bullet": "round","valueField": "user_16"},       
              {"balloonText": "[[value]]", "bullet": "round","valueField": "user_18"},       
              {"balloonText": "[[value]]", "bullet": "round","valueField": "user_23"}
             ],
    "categoryField": "competence",
    "legend": {"align": "center", "markerType": "circle", "position": "right","marginright": 80, "automargin": false, "combineLegend": true, 
    "data": [
            {"title": "Beheer B van (Proeftuin)"},       
            {"title": "Acda W. (Willem)"},       
            {"title": "Baard B. (Bas)"},         
            {"title": "Bedrijf 1 - Jan Stucadoor"}]}    
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by putting the legend text in the graphs data:

"graphs": [
{"balloonText": "[[value]] - van Beheer B van (Proeftuin)", "bullet": "round","valueField": "user_25"},
{"balloonText": "[[value]] - van Acda W. (Willem)", "bullet": "round","valueField": "user_26"},
{"balloonText": "[[value]] - van Rutte M.E. (Mark)", "bullet": "round","valueField": "user_27"},
{"balloonText": "[[value]] - van Bedrijf 1 - Persoon 1", "bullet": "round","valueField": "user_33"}]